# Valuation functional

Tags: arbitrage, finance-mathematics, economics

> Consider an economy with $J = 2$ assets and $S = 3$ states. The $J\times S$ payoff matrix for the two assets is $$X = \begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 3 & 3\\
> 1 & 1 & 0\\
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   and the asset prices $P' = (5/9,2)$.
>
> Determine whether there are arbitrage opportunities in this market. In addition, find the minimum and maximum prices for the risk free asset.

Attempted solution: We have $$P = X q =  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3 & 3\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
q_1\\
q_2\\
q_3 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
3q_2 + 3 q_3\\
q_1 + q_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
I believe we need to fix $q_2$ but the solution states that $q = (5/9 - q_2,q_2,6/9 - q_2)$. For $q_2\in (0,5/9)$ all $q$'s are positive so there is no arbitrage. $q_f \in (6/9,11/9)$.

I am not sure how we arrive at this solution any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in my professors question he changed $$P = \begin{pmatrix}
2\\
5/9
\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus when we fix $q_2$ we get $$q = (5/9 - q_2,q_2,6/9 - q_2)$$ Thus for $q_2\in (0,5/9)$ all $q$'s are positive so there is no arbitrage. Then clearly $q_f = (6/9,11/9)$